# In Clojure, is a distributed atom in Datomic the same concept as a distributed atom in Avout?

Tags: clojure, state, distributed, datomic

When I look at the [Avout](https://github.com/liebke/avout) Framework - I see an advanced system for distributed transactional state in Clojure. There is a concept of a [Distributed Atom](https://github.com/liebke/avout/blob/master/src/avout/atoms.clj#L33).

Now I create a distributed atom in my code - I'm going to call it a `datom`. But this triggers off a thought of another Clojure Framework **Datom**ic ([link](http://www.datomic.com/)).

Now it appears that Datomic is a distributed mechanism for storing facts (called **Datoms**).

Now I have some program state I'd like to distribute. (eg Two real-time tanks on a grid with multiple different clients without turns). I'm trying to make a decision about distributing this state using Avout or Datomic - and even if I can use both of these to solve my problem.

My question is: **In Clojure, is a distributed atom in Datomic the same concept as a distributed atom in Avout?**

Comment: a Datom in Datomic is just a tuple of entity, attribute, value, tx/time. and added/retracted. see http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Datom.html

Comment: I'm not sure about putting Avout in production, but it could well be a solution otherwise (I haven't used it). Datomic doesn't seem really suited to  games in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are two very different things. A Datomic datom is an immutable tuple, an Avout atom is a distributed atom. Datomic's datom is not short for distributed atom, it is a play on words from "datum", which is the singular form of "data".